# ScrollTop on a div, Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a div with text, and after I submit that text, I get from server new data. If I was on the bottom of first text, the second text that I get from server is also on the bottom, and I want to move to the top of the text after I get data.

```
<b-row class="question-top mb-3" >
    <b-col xl="12" md="12" sm="12" xs="12">
    <div class="question-editor"> 
        <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="free_text" :disabled="editorDisabled"></ckeditor>
    </div>
    </b-col>
</b-row>

//style
.question-editor{
    overflow-y: auto; //so here I have the scroll
}
methods(){
  getData() {
    axios...CODE..

    //and here I try to move to the top of that div
    var topElement =  document.querySelector('.question-editor');
    scrollTo(topElement, 0, 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollTop function is part of the window object or the element itself

in your case it would be:

```
topElement.scrollTo (100,0)
```

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Comment: Almost works, but is not top , more like 10%, from the top, not sure why..

Comment: You have to change 0 with 100, and works. (100, 0) . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var topElement =  document.querySelector('.question-editor');
    topElement.scrollIntoView(true);
```

For more clarity doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: @Beusebiu I tested that in chrome's console it seems to work smooth.

Comment: How to test: 
In stackOverflow in this page only open console and type 

var element = document.querySelector('#question-header');
element.scrollIntoView()

Comment: In console I tested, here works (on stack-overflow), but in my app nothing.

Comment: Seeing your code it seems fine, Just check is that even getting hit to function.